# Add button overlay on hover to image which is link

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am primarily a backend engineer so forgive me if this question has a very obvious answer but I have a set of images which when clicked on navigate to new pages.  I am trying to implement a way so that hovering over the image displays a button that can be clicked to trigger a modal popping up.  I am wondering if there is a way to do this since the image itself is contained in an anchor tag.  The button overlayed should have an ng-click attribute

Here is the existing code.  Once again sorry if this is a very newbie question.

```
<a ng-href="/{{similarCampaign.crossSellPath}}" ng-attr-title="{{similarCampaign.name}}">
  <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 150px" ng-src="{{similarCampaign.mockupUrlSmall}}" ng-attr-alt="{{similarCampaign.name}}" ng-attr-nopin="{{similarCampaign.stealthy ? 'nopin' : ''}}"/>
  <!-- button overlay of image above -->
</a>
```

Comment: can you show us working fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

wrap everything within a div with a position: relative, and add a button outside of the a href, with position: absolute, then center it where you want it.